html contact form with php email not working
I have created an html contact form to work with a php file for website visitors to send emails to me, but it is not sending them to my inbox. Both files are in my public_html directory.
This is the html contactus.htm form
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="send_email.php" method="post" id="contact-form">

<h2>Contact us</h2>

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
<br>

<label for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
<br>

<label for="message">Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
<br>

<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

This is the send_email.php file
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "admin@xxxxxxxxxx.xx"; // this is your Email address
$name = $_POST['name'];
$from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
$message = $_POST['message'];

echo "Your email was sent. Thank you";
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
}
?>

I checked and rechecked the coding with online examples but I can't find any problem with it.

There doesn't seem to be any send command in your send_email.php ?

"I can't find any problem" - really? Where is the call to PHPMailer that will actually send the email?

I only have a limited knowledge of coding. I added this line to the send_email.php page. Is this the correct code? It still does not work.  mail($to, $name, "From:" . $email, $message);

Sending email doesn't 'just work' and it's much more than adding a call to mail(). mail() assumes that there is a working mail server to send the mail to, and sending email reliably requires significant configuration on your DNS.  Do you have a mail server? Have you set up SPF, DKIM and DMARC? These are off topic for [so], but you could make life easier by downloading PHPMailer and searching for questions here on how to use it.

Thank you. More involved than I thought but I will attempt phpmailer installation.
